# How to Set a Password on the my sql server 2005 Database

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have a database in sql server 2005.i want to setup a password on the database.
can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of database encryption: yes

[SQL Server, T-SQL, ASP.NET, Javascript, SAP, ABAP Programming

Kodyaz Development Resources](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-2005-database-encryption-step-by-step.aspx)